# Starting Firefox without the last open tabs

Tags: firefox

I'm running Firefox 9.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 (that's on Linux Mint).

One of the tabs has a site loaded which crashes Firefox each time it loads.

Therefore, I can't close the tab quickly enough after starting Firefox to stop that site loading.

How can I make Firefox "forget" its current session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can also start Firefox in Safe Mode by quitting Firefox and then
>   going to your Terminal and running:
>       firefox -safe-mode

Source: [How to start Firefox in Safe Mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode)

A bit late but I confirm it's normal behavior, safe mode only loads the strict minimum from your profile in order to prevent cases like these.

Comment: From safe mode, can I get Firefox to forget the tabs open in "normal" mode?

Comment: Tools/Options/General/StartUp and set "When Firefox starts" to "Show a blank page"

Comment: Fixed by just entering safe mode: When I started safe mode, it gave me the screen "Well that's embarrassing". I was able to choose "Start new session". Firefox in normal mode now starts with my normal homepage only, which was the setting already...

Comment: Safe/Troubleshooting mode does NOT prevent opened tabs from re-opening, so this does NOT solve the problem.